# How do you do an automatic git pull on remote server?

Tags: php, git

Before I begin, I know there are a lot of questions similar to this one, but I am really having difficulty finding a concise, secure, best practice since the feedback on them has been so widely varied.

#### What I want to do:

1. Complete work on my local machine on a development branch.
2. Push changes to git.  Git posts to a webhook URL and automatically has my remote server pull the changes on a development site.
3. Once QA'd and confirmed to be proper on the development site, push the master branch to the production site (on the same server as the development site).

#### Where I am at:

I have git installed on my local machine and the remote server.  I can push mods to the development branch to git.  On the remote server, I can pull the updates and it works like a charm.  The problem is that I cannot get the remote server to automatically update when changes are pushed from my local machine.

#### My questions are:

1. For the remote server development site directory, should I `git init` or `git init --bare`?  I don't plan on having updates made on the server itself.  I would like my dev team to work locally and push mods to the server.  I believe I need to use git init as the working tree is needed to set-up a remote alias to the git repository, but I wanted to confirm.
2. I am pretty sure the webhook post from git issue is due to user privileges.  How can I *safely* get around this?  I have read many tutorials that suggest updating git hook files, but I feel as though that is more drastic of a measure than I need to take.  I would love to be able to have the webhook hit a URL that safely pulls the files without adding a boatload of code (if it is possible).

I am a web developer by nature, so git and sysadmin tasks are generally the bane of my existence.  Again, I know this question is similar to others, but I have yet to find a comprehensive, concise, secure, and most logical approach to resolving the issue.  I am about 16 hours in and have officially hit the "going in circles with no progress" point.

Comment: Wow it is kind of impossible to find a simple solutions to this. Makes me miss SVN a little...

Answer (score 26):

You can do this quite easily with GitHub service hooks.

You ll need to create one more file that will handle the process of performing the git pull. Add a new file, called github.php (or anything you wish ), and add:

```
<?php `git pull`;
```

Save that file, and upload it to the repository directory on your server. Then, go to `Services Hooks -> Post-Receive URL` and  copy the URL to that file, and paste it into the “Post-Receive URL”  E.g. `http://demo.test.com/myfolder/github.php`

So, when you push, GitHub will automatically visit this URL, thus causing your server to perform a `git pull`.

To see this in more details to go to [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/the-perfect-workflow-with-git-github-and-ssh/)

Comment: isn't this not secure? 
So any user can just run the url and pull stuff :/

Comment: @RickSanchez I don't think security is an issue because you can define a `secret` for instance github: `https://developer.github.com/webhooks/creating/#secret`. All you have to do is check the headers.

Comment: Superb I didnot know that php feature.

Comment: Is this solution still applicable in 2024, as I would love to reproduce something similar.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same exact issue, strong in code and development skills, weak in sysadmin skills. When I was finally ready to push code I had to ask a [GitHub](https://github.com/) rep what their suggested method was, and they responded with Capistrano. It's a [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) application that runs commands (such as git pull) on remote servers, along with pretty much any other command you can imagine.

Here a few articles you can read to get more info:

- [GitHub - Deploy with Capistrano](http://help.github.com/deploy-with-capistrano/)
- [How to compile the Capistrano stack on your *nix system](http://melikedev.com/2011/01/31/linux-centos-64-ruby-rubygems-capistrano/)
- [Another example of how to deploy code with Capistrano](http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/deployments/deploy-with-capistrano.html)

Not going to lie, the learning curve was pretty steep, but once you start working with Capistrano, you will see that it works well for pushing code. I develop my applications in Symfony and I have my Capistrano set-up to pull code, clear cache and clear log files, all in one command from my local machine.