# How to add git hook to non /var/www folder

Tags: git, lamp

I found this question which tells how to create a git hook to automatically pull updates to a folder [Automatic git pull on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542158/how-do-you-do-an-automatic-git-pull-on-remote-server)

Basically, it says to add a php file to the folder, then the hook will do an http request to execute the script.

My problem is that I am updating python scripts that are not in the /var/www folder, but rather in the /usr folder.

I don't want these files accessible via the web, so is there a way to execute a `git pull` request on a remote server for a folder outside /var/www?

Comment: The linked answer saying to install a PHP script is just implementing a cheap way to run `git pull` without explicitly logging in to the server, and specifically requires your project to be hosted on GitHub, and deployed on a web server with PHP.  The hook part is specific to GitHub, not to `git` itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I automatically deploy my app after a git push ( GitHub and node.js)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132144/how-can-i-automatically-deploy-my-app-after-a-git-push-github-and-node-js)

Comment: Probably a better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279169/deploy-a-project-using-git-push

Comment: @tripleee that answer looks about right. I wasn't aware that you could use user@server:filename to execute a file from an http request. I am using gitlab, so I will try it and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your bare repo (which includes your hook) anywhere you want.

Then the hook can execute a script again placed anywhere you want.

None of those two elements needs to be in `/var/www`.

---

The idea is:

- [declare a webhook in your GitLab project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18901502/6309) for a [push event](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/web_hooks/web_hooks.md#push-events),
- add a script listening to the JSON payload on the remote server: that script will do a `git pull`.
  It can be a [php script (as in this example)](http://behindcompanies.com/2014/01/a-simple-script-for-deploying-code-with-githubs-webhooks/) or a script in any other language.

Comment: I have the hook in the folder, but I have to do an http request to access the php file that will execute the file.

Comment: @pekasus why not have a local copy of that php file?

Comment: You mean in the folder on the remote server? Thats where I have it.  Would it work if I put the php script in the www folder, then add the full path to the bash script?

Comment: @pekasus I mean when the hook is trigger, it should execute a script which is on the same server as the hook.

Comment: I don't understand how that would work. I have to execute the git pull on the remote server.  I am using gitlab if that changes anything. Could I place the script on gitlab and have that execute a git pull on the remote server?

Comment: @pekasus on gitlab, you declare your project webhook (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18901502/6309) The script listening to the JSON payload is on your remote server, and it can execute the git pull.

Comment: Got it. I'll give that a shot. If you put that in the answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!