# "Git pull" on server after every "git push" from local machine

Tags: git

My usage of git is very simple.
Basically I do smth like this on my local machine:

```
echo 'Update' >> README.md
git add . && git commit -m 'update' && git push -u origin master
```

Then on server:

```
git pull
```

That's it.

And I am doing it every time I make changes on my local machine.
Seems to me I can optimize this somehow, but I haven't found any git command to deal with this.

Is there a way not to print `git pull` every time there is a change?
And maybe there is a way to automatically `add && commit && push`?

Comment: It sounds like you want a backup system, not a VCS.

Comment: *git pull* on your server ? the same as your git server ?

Comment: @axiac How does it sound for you like that? - Hes trying to optimize his workflow.

Comment: @Xatenev *"... automatically `add && commit && push`..."*

Comment: why not push on the server too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second thing you can create a script.
E.g. create a file:

```
sudo nano /usr/local/bin/git-update
```

paste:

```
git add . && git commit -m 'update' && git push -u origin master`
```

then do

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/git-update
```

and use your new command (`git-update`).

Comment: Thanks! That doesn't solve the problem but I print less now, and fast-learned how to create custom commmands:)

Comment: I'm glad I could help you :)
Btw: instead of using advanced automation tools which are great, but you are beginner I think, you could create a cron job on your server for git pull.  
  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414140/git-auto-pull-using-cronjob  
  
Waiting for futher questions! :)

Comment: Did with script `while true
do      
        cd dir/ && git pull && cd -
        sleep 5
done
` and nohup

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is the normal behavior: you push on your local and pull on the server.

To automatically perform pulls you would need some kind of continueos integration tool like

http://capistranorb.com/
or https://jenkins.io/

In the special case of using **github**, refer to this question/answer: [How do you do an automatic git pull on remote server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542158/how-do-you-do-an-automatic-git-pull-on-remote-server)

Yes you can add git aliases, that performs add commit and push all together for you https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases

Comment: Thanks for git aliases. It seems to be better then adding bash command.

Comment: rating is too low to rate:)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what you really want is to deploy after a git push, there is a lot written online about that.

`git pull` can potentially fail on the remote if some files have been changed there. You need a `post-update` [git hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) that triggers a script that utilises, for example, rsync, to do the actual deployment, and the nature of the  hook takes care of making it happen on every push.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GitHub, you can use their Webhooks feature to listen to `push` events and do things accordingly.

https://developer.github.com/webhooks/

There are tools such as [chimneypot](https://github.com/chimneypot/chimneypot) which allow you to write small scripts that do things on these events.